# Error: 'asp:DropList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, webforms

I have a dynamically filled droplist in my application nested within a formview that is throwing the above error:

Here is the html for control that is throwing the error. I have this in both the Edit and the Insert Template

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CreatedByDropList" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CreatedBy") %>' runat="server" />
```

The CreatedBy variable is being fed from a SqlDataSource which also feeds the rest of the elements in the formview.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [PostId], [Title], [CreatedBy], [IsPublished] 
FROM [cs_Blog_Post] WHERE PostID = @PostID"
```

Behind the scenes I have the following script in an attempt to fill the dropList with a datatable.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT RLS.RoleName [RoleName], URS.UserID [UserID], USRS.UserName[UserName], USRS.FirstName[FirstName], USRS.LastName[LastName]
    FROM [Roles] RLS Inner JOIN [Users] USRS LEFT JOIN [UserRoles] URS 
    ON USRS.[UserID] = URS.[UserID] ON RLS.[RoleID] = URS.[RoleID] 
    WHERE RLS.[RoleName] = 'Blog Editors'",conn);
conn.Open();

using (SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader1.Read())
    {
        int numUserID = reader1.GetInt32(1);
        string strFirstName = reader1.GetString(3);
        string strLastName = reader1.GetString(4);
        string newUserName = strFirstName + " " + strLastName;

        ddlCreatedBy.Items.Add(new ListItem(newUserName, numUserID.ToString()));
    }
```

When I run this code, and put the formview in edit mode I get this error.

***'CreatedByDropList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.Parameter name: value***.

However if I remove the `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CreatedBy") %>'` it gives this error

***DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'numUserID'.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, it seems to me that you are initializing `SelectedValue` in the `aspx` file before it was filled from the SQL command you are refereing to. Have a look at the [WebForm Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

I think you should set this value in an event handler like the `Page_Load`.

For the second one, you looks like trying to access the `numUserID` key of an array/list somewhere else than the source code you provided in your question (like a GridView or something).